# Perforce: How to automatically check out binary when source gets compiled

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2005, perforce, p4v

I would like to create a mechanism by which I automatically submit the executable corresponding to the updated code.  My development environment is Visual Studio 2005 and I use the windows GUI client to submit changes.

Ideally, I would like to ensure latest binary is submitted in the same change list as the code changes.

My requirements are:

- The code should be recompiled and binary should be checked out when source code dependencies change.
- Related documentation / non-source files do not affect binary
- Perforce should complain when sources are changed and submitted but the binary isn't included in the change list.

How could I enforce these rules?  Is it possible to create a P4 script that runs before each submission?  Also, is it possible to write a Visual Studio script that automatically checks out the executable before compiling?

Thanks,

Shahar

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish most of this without too much work.

If you include the output directories in your Perforce workspace, you can easily just check them in every time you do a build.  (You might want to talk to the Perforce admin about using a 'purge' option so you're not storing thousands of copies of binaries.)  You can use a trigger to make sure that source code in certain directories is always submitted with a binary.